# C++ Error: explicit qualification

Tags: c++

What do these errors mean?

```
Vector.cpp:13: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of â€˜Vectorâ€™ with no type
Vector.cpp:13: error: explicit qualification in declaration of â€˜void Vector::Vector(double, double, double)â€™
```

The C++ (Line 13 is the Vector::Vector( ...):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace Vector
{
    Vector::Vector( double x, double y, double z)
    {
        a = x;
        b = y;
        c = z;
    }
/*
    double Vector::dot(const Vector &v) const
    {
        return (a*v.a)+(b*v.b)+(c*v.c);
    }
*/
   Vector Vector::operator+(const Vector &v) const
   {
       Vector v1( a + v.a, b + v.b, c + v.c );
       return v1;
   }

   Vector Vector::operator-(const Vector &v) const
   {
       Vector v1( a - v.a, b - v.b, c - v.c );
       return v1;
   }

   bool Vector::operator==(const Vector &v) const
   {
       if( (a == v.a) && (b == v.b) && (c == v.c) )
       {
           return true;
       }
       else
       {
           return false;
       }
   }

   Vector Vector::operator*(const Vector &v) const
   {
       Vector v1( b*v.c - c*v.b, c*v.a - a*v.c, a*v.b - b*v.a );
       return v1;
   }

   ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const Vector &v)
   {
       out << "<" << v.a << ", " << v.b << ", " << v.c << ">";
       return out;
   }

   istream& operator>>(istream &in, Vector &v)
   {
       in >> v.a;
       in >> v.b;
       in >> v.c;
       return in;
   }
/*
    double length( Vector v )
    {
        return sqrt( (v.a*v.a)+(v.b*v.b)+(v.c*v.c) );
    }
*/
} // end namespace Vector
```

The header file:

```
#ifndef _VECTOR_H
#define _VECTOR_H

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

namespace Vector
{


class Vector
{
private:
    double a;
    double b;
    double c;

public:
    Vector( double x=0.0, double y=0.0, double z=0.0);

    double dot(const Vector &v) const;
    Vector operator+(const Vector &v) const;
    Vector operator-(const Vector &v) const;
    bool operator==(const Vector &v) const;
    Vector operator*(const Vector &v) const;
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const Vector &v);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream &in, Vector &v);


}; // end Vector class

    double length(Vector v);

} //end namespace Vector
#endif  /* _VECTOR_H */
```

Comment: In addition to the erroneous return value, you can't define default parameters in the definition. Only the header file gets those.

Comment: post the whole thing - not just pieces

Comment: so.. is your problem solved now?

Comment: I posted all the code... @Jagannath No its not... still same errors even after removing the void as GMan said

Comment: include the header file in the cpp file.

Comment: if thats line 13 what have you left out, cos i count it as line 6 . operator+ is line 13 but thats commented out

Comment: I left out comments at the beginning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the major problem is that your cpp files didn't include your header file.

Answer (score 4):

Constructors have no return type, not even void. Just remove the `void` and you're fine.

Comment: Try GMan's suggestion, also make sure you have the c'tor declared in the class (`Vector(double x,double y,double z);` somewhere in the declaration of `Vector`).

Comment: Some of your operators return bool, but the should return `Vector`.

Comment: Also, you need to rename your namespace (using the same name as for the class leeds to disambiguities).

Answer (score 1):

Include the header file in the cpp file. Also, the code has some design issues. operator+ should return const Vector and the same case with operator-.